# CDF of two dice throws that equal doubles

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I'm trying to find the expected value, variance, and cdf of getting doubles when throwing 2 dice. So the set that I want to represent is {(1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (6,6)}.

I calculated the expected value (E(X)) = 1/6
The variance (Var(X)) = 5/36

However, how do I calculate the CDF of x for specific dice throws such as getting doubles?

Comment: What the's probability of getting at most $0$ doubles?  At most $1$ double?  In one roll, there aren't any other possible values.

Comment: So the possibility of getting 1 double is 0 --> <= 1 and the possibility of getting 0 doubles is > 1 --> 6? Is that correct?

Comment: With two die you can get one double only. The probability for that is $\frac16$. But I do not understand how the random variable X is defined.

Comment: What does "> 1 --> 6" mean?  And it's not "possibility" but "probability".

Comment: @saulspatz sorry my bad. So basically the way I'm reading what you said. The distribution would look like:  (-infinity, 1) [1, infinity). So in a table, you would have the probability of 1 double (which is 1/6), and the probability of no doubles (which is 5/6). Hooe this helps make it more clear.

Comment: I think I'll write an answer.

Comment: To obtain the cdf it is a good idea to write down the pdf. The pdf for the number of doubles in one throw with two die is

$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases} \frac56, \ x=0 \\  \frac16, \ x=1 \\ 0, \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ 

Therefore the cdf is 

$$F_X(x)=\begin{cases} 0,  x<0  \\ \frac56, \ 0\leq x<1  \\  1, \ x \geq 1 \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be a random variable representing the number of doubles in one roll of two dice.  Then the cdf of $X$ is defined by $$F(x)=\Pr(X\leq x)$$ so that $$F(0) = \frac56\\F(1)=1$$

I don't think it's customary to have the domain of the cdf of a discrete random variable be the real numbers, as you seem to do in your comment, but if we wanted to, we could write $$G(x)=\cases{0,& x<0\\ \frac56,& $0\leq x$ < 1\\1,& $x\geq1$}$$

Comment: I gitcha, ok yea that's what I was looking for. Then the table distribution would look like: (- infinity, 0) [0, 1) [1, infinity) with the values of P(x) beneath them being 0, 5/6, and 1/6 respectively.

Comment: Is it correct that the values are 0, 5/6, and 1/6 in that function? Or do I replace 1/6 with 1? Little confused on that. Like if I was to make a graph of the distribution is what I mean

Comment: The values are $0,\frac56,1$ as it says.  Look at the definition of cdf again.  You seem to be thinking of the probability mass function, which is quite a different thing.

Comment: Ohhh ok, I see now. Thanks!